# DSE changing cassandra to use vnodes

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

We want to deploy DSE cluster of 3 nodes, where each node is *Analytics* running Spark.

We want to use vnodes in cassandra, because it enables much more even data distribution and easier adding of the nodes. We deploy DSE on AWS, using one of the available AMI images.

Although DSE by default deploys Cassandra cluster using single token nodes, we have to manually change *cassandra.yaml* file on all the nodes.

According to [datastax documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/config/configVnodes.html), I should:

- uncomment *num_tokens* field (I left 256 default value)
- leave *initial_token* field unassigned

After that, when I do *nodetool status* command, I see that my cluster still uses single token mode.

According to [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html), I should restart nodes in the cluster, so that changes take effect.

But after nodes are restarted both thru OPS center or AWS console, I get errors, nodes are in *unresponsive state*, and I cannot use *nodetool* command on my nodes, with error:

> Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

How to enable vnodes on DSE when deployed using AMI image?

Thank you

Comment: connection refused because cassandra is not running. what errors appears in the system.log?

Comment: You can't just switch from single tokens to vnodes. You'd need to add a new dc with vnodes and decommission the old one. Is this a production cluster with data? If not you could clear out your data commitlog and saved caches dirs and start again with vnodes.

Comment: But how to start with vnodes using Datastax AMI on EC2?

Because by default AMI uses single token, so after cluster is already deployed, I need to change to vnodes...